# Java com JavaFX

Tags: java, thread, javafx, multithreading, task

Pessoal estou tentando fazer uma chamada de thread ao abrir a tela de cadastro de clientes, mais a minha tela não esta abrindo, alguem pode ajudar??

```
    @FXML
    void OpenCliente(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            //CREATING A THREAD
            Task<Void> ts = new Task<Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception{
                    ClienteExec cliente = new ClienteExec();
                    cliente.start(new Stage());
                    return  null;
                }
                @Override
                protected void succeeded(){
                    super.succeeded();
                }
            };
            new Thread(ts).start();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Não se pode manipular elementos da interface usando Task, provavelmente deve ter dado o erro: Not on FXApplication Thread

Comment: qual o método que devo usar para abrir uma thread em uma cena?

Comment: Não pude responder porque acabou ficando um código sem contexto, você disse qual o problema mas não qual o objetivo. Porque você tem que abrir a tela de clientes usando thread?